# How do I convert from object to string

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell so this will probably be easy to answer. Suppose I create an array like so:

```
$array1 = "a", "b", "c"
```

Then I create another array:

```
$array2 = $array1|select-object{$_}
```

What I would like to do is to join all the values in $array2 so I end up with the string "a b c", but using -join " " on $array2 just produces an empty result. Can someone explain to me how I can solve this?

Comment: Why are you using `|select-object{$_}` when copying `array1` to `array2`?

Comment: It was only to emphasize my example. I would never use that approeach but I guess I wasn't too clear on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `$array2 = $array1|select-object{$_}` with `$array2 = $array1 | select-object` or `$array2 = $array1`

```
$array1 = "a", "b", "c"

#expected output: a b c
$array1 -join " "

#here it is
$array2 = $array1 | select-object

#expected output: a b c
$array2 -join " "

#here it is
$array2 = $array1

#expected output: a b c
$array2 -join " "
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do what you need here in PowerShell is

```
"$array1"
```

or

```
'' + $array1
```

both of which will join the array elements with `$OFS` or space if `$OFS` is `$null`.

But as others have noted, your `Select-Object` call is wrong. Select-Object takes property names, not a scriptblock. Maybe you wanted `ForEach-Object` in that case?

Comment: What about casting like this: `[string]$array1`? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Should work too. I think the best practice would be an explicit `-join` if that's what you want. Interactively I usually go for the shortest variant, mostly because I frequently golf in PowerShell, too.

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
$array2 = $array1|select-object{$_}
```

in

```
$array2 = $array1
```

then

```
$array2 -join ' '
```

works!